# Syntax Error in the deep-speare quatrain generator

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:

File "sonnet_gen.py",
line 106 quatrain.append(q)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

when running the script
the area / the error is here (it's for a school project:

```
        #quatrain generation
        for _ in range(args.num_samples):

            #generate some random sentences
            print("\nTemperature =", args.temp_min, "-", args.temp_max)
            q, probs = mgen.generate(sess, idxword, idxchar, charxid, wordxchar, wordxid[pad_symbol],
                wordxid[end_symbol], wordxid[unk_symbol], charxid[" "], avoid_symbols, stopwords,
                args.temp_min, args.temp_max, 4, 400, args.sent_sample, args.rm_threshold, args.verbose)
            for line_id, line in enumerate(q):
                print("  %02d  [%.2f]  %s" % (line_id+1, probs[line_id], line)
                quatrain.append(q)
    #save generated samples in a pickle file
    if args.save_pickle and len(quatrains) > 0:
        cPickle.dump(quatrains, open(args.save_pickle, "w"))
```

Comment: you are missing a parentheses on the print() above the append()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In the future, please try to see that your code is formatted correctly in your question.  This is especially important with Python, where indentation is part of the language syntax.  @catasaurus has your answer.  It is the `print()` line above (line 105 I assume) that has the error.  The compiler just can't know that until line 106, so that's technically where the problem occurs.

Comment: @CryptoFool What's wrong with the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this area:

```py
for line_id, line in enumerate(q):
  print("  %02d  [%.2f]  %s" % (line_id+1, probs[line_id], line)
  quatrain.append(q)
```

You have two opening parentheses on the middle `print` line, but only one closing parenthesis. You will need to add another closing parenthesis to close the call to `print`.

Comment: This is a simple typo, not worthy of a formal answer.

Comment: @JohnGordon Would you mind pointing me towards a resource that explains what justifies an answer versus an answer in a comment? I wasn't able to find anything in my searching, thanks!

Comment: If you click the "Close" link on a question, then select "community-specific reason", you will see that "not reproducible or caused by a typo" is given as one possible reason for closing a question.  Such questions ought to be closed, not answered.